# How to change mysql to postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

as in title any one can help me with conversion from mysql to postgres

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_roles MODIFY 'roleId' tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

and the second one

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_users MODIFY 'userId' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=20;
```

with error syntax error at near "MODIFY"

Comment: Have you considered looking up DDL statements in the Postgresql docs?

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the column name.

Comment: I did and there is still the same error, but acutally now is giving me an error in the last line `ALTER TABLE tbl_users MODIFY userId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=20;`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 0):

i did in a different way

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_roles (
  roleId tinyint(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4
);
```

also in table in second table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_users (
  userId int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=20,
);
```

and there is no errors